# Windows 10 VPN client is not working

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-10

In Windows 10 (an upgrade from Windows 8.1), old VPN PPTP connections were not correctly migrated.

Created new VPN PPTP connection which was not working.  Error message:

```
A Connection to the remote computer could not be established.
```

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question, but don't do it ***in the question***.

Answer (score 38):

1. Open Windows **Device Manager**
2. Expand **Network adapters**

[image]

3. Right click and **Uninstall** the following **WAN Miniport** devices

   - **WAN Miniport (IP)**
   - **WAN Miniport (IPv6)**
   - **WAN Miniport (PPTP)**
4. Click the root computer element at the very top of Device Manager
5. Click **Scan for hardware changes** button
6. The WAN Miniport devices will be re-installed
7. Attempt to create or connect to your VPN connection

Comment: if its not showing : view->show hidden devices

Comment: I didn't know what "Refresh" meant in this context, but clicking "Scan for changes" worked for me

Comment: This solution is not working :(

Comment: This worked for me. Thank!

Comment: Thank you, it works!  You should also uninstall WAN Miniport (L2TP) if your VPN is L2TP/IPSec (my case).